# UIScrollView do not scroll

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a UIScrollView that do not scroll at all. If I enable bouncing, I can scroll far enough to the sides to see that there is content outside of the view, but it snaps right back to the origin when I release. I have paging turned on, but I get the same behavior if I turn it off. 
I have auto layout turned off. 
In the IB, the scrollView is in a MainViewController, correctly linked up to the IBOutlet as below.

```
@interface MainViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        // I might be doing this wrong, but it returns a PosterView object just like I want it to.
        NSArray *view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"posterView" owner:self options:nil];
        [[view objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:frame];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:[view objectAtIndex:0]];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 3, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
```

If I use this method though, it scrolls correctly.

```
-(void)scrollToPage:(NSInteger)page{
    float pageWidth = [self.scrollView frame].size.width;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(page*pageWidth,0) animated:YES];
}
```

I have tried implementing the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and overriding `scrollViewDidScroll`, but it is never called (unless I have enable bouncing, like I mentioned earlier).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UIScrollView` only scrolls when having a `contentSize` larger than its frame size. If it doesn't scroll might mean that its `contentSize` is not large enough. So check what its `contentSize` is after setting it.

If the `contentSize` is as you are expecting it to be then check for if the scrollView is `scrollEnabled` or not. Sometimes enabling bounce creates an impression that the scrolling is working. Also, if the scrolling is not enabled,setting the `contentOffset` works in that case too because then it moves the content according to the provided size as argument.

Comment: contentSize.width is 960, and the frame is obviously 320, so that shouldn't be the problem.. Scrolling is set to enabled in the IB, tried doing it in the code but without success!

Comment: The code you provided looks fine. The content size remains (3*320,480) throughout? Or maybe get reset somehow

Comment: You are right, it DOES reset after viewDidLoad! By setting the contentSize the first time you try to scroll, it now works! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the `contentSize` inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. It is late enough in the view life cycle for it not to be reset by any other method, and doesn't require you to check whether the view is scrolling for the first time.

Comment: +1 This is the solution only working for me. Also you have to put scrollView as subview of controller's view (scrollView cannot be directly controller's view). Strange though...

Comment: Constraints caused my contentSize to get overwritten in viewDidLoad, but why should constraints affect contentSize? Sometimes I really hate constraints.