# UIScrollView is not scrolling while the scroll view height is set to 1000 and the content height 2000

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am building an application form for data entry in iPad app, that needs more space.I decided to use the UIScrollView for that purpose and added some subviews (UILabel, UITextField,...). The only problem I am facing is that scrolling is not working !!

Here is .h code :

```
 @interface ViewController4_modified : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>

 @property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *formScroller; // <-- 
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *formLabel;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *formFisrtNameTextField;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *formFirstMidTextField;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *formSecondMidTextField;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *formLastNameTextField;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *formGenderPicker;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *formBDDatePicker;

 @end
```

Here is .m code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {    

self.formScroller.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.formScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768, 2000);
self.formScroller.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0, 0.0, 44.0, 0.0);
self.formScroller.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0, 0.0, 44.0, 0.0);


[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

}
```

Comment: check scrollEnabled property is YES or NO

Comment: it is enabled in the xcode interface and in the code
self.formScroller.scrollEnabled = YES;

Comment: maybe your scrollview contentSize gets reset after viewdidLoad as per  this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475487/uiscrollview-do-not-scroll?rq=1

Comment: Can you move your code to viewWillAppeare: and let me know is it works?

Comment: @Greg .. I did ,, still not working :/

Comment: Try debug whats your frame and content size on the end of viewDidLoad and move your [super viewDidLoad]; on beginning of the method.

Comment: nothing happened .. I think it is xcode issue don't you think?

Comment: Maybe can be an autolayout conflict. Did you disable it and tried again?

Comment: Other suggestion: on your viewDidLoad method, move your code to AFTER [super viewDidLoad].

Comment: Thanks @scollaco it was Auto layout issue ,, it needed to be disabled :) :)

Comment: Thank you All Guys Greg, and suhit for your support :)